# Speeding up AVR function pointers

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega

I have a program for avr where I would like to use a pointer to a method. But why is using function pointer over normal call almost 4 times slower?? And how do I speed it up?

I have:

```
void simple_call(){ PORTB |= _BV(1); }

void (*simple)() = &simple_call;
```

Then if I compile with -O3 and call:

```
simple_call()
```

it takes 250ns to complete. If I instead call:

```
simple()
```

it takes 960ns to complete!!

How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why is it slower??

You see a 710 ns increase in time.  For a 16 MHz clock, that time is 11 ticks.

It is not really fair to say 4X because the time increase is a constant overhead for the function pointer.  In your case, the function body is tiny, so the overhead is relatively large.  But if you had a case where the function was large and took 1 ms to execute, the time increase would still be 710 ns and you would be asking why does the function pointer take 0.07% longer?

To see why one approach is faster than another, you need to get at the assembler code.  Using build tools such as Eclipse allows you the get an assembler listing from the GCC compiler by adding command line options not available with the Arduino IDE.  This is invaluable to figure out what is going on.

Here is a section of the assembler listing showing what you think is going on:

```
simple_call();
   308: 0e 94 32 01     call    0x264   ; 0x264 <_Z11simple_callv>

simple();
   30c: e0 91 0a 02     lds r30, 0x020A
   310: f0 91 0b 02     lds r31, 0x020B
   314: 19 95           eicall
```

These listings show the source code and assembler produced by the compiler.  To make sense of that and figure out timing, you need the [Atmel AVR instruction reference](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf) which contains descriptions of every instruction and the number of clock ticks they take.  The simple_call() is maybe what you expect and takes 4 ticks.  The simple() says:

```
LDS = load address byte - 2 ticks
LDS = load address byte - 2 ticks
EICALL = indirect call to address loaded - 4 ticks
```

Those both call the function simple_call():

```
void simple_call(){ PORTB |= _BV(1); }
 264:   df 93           push    r29
 266:   cf 93           push    r28
 268:   cd b7           in  r28, 0x3d   ; 61
 26a:   de b7           in  r29, 0x3e   ; 62
 26c:   a5 e2           ldi r26, 0x25   ; 37
 26e:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
 270:   e5 e2           ldi r30, 0x25   ; 37
 272:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 274:   80 81           ld  r24, Z
 276:   82 60           ori r24, 0x02   ; 2
 278:   8c 93           st  X, r24
 27a:   cf 91           pop r28
 27c:   df 91           pop r29
 27e:   08 95           ret
```

So the function pointer should take just 4 more ticks and be small compared to all the instructions in the function method.

---

Above, I said **should** and **what you think is going on**.  I lied a bit: the assembler above is for no optimizations.

You used the optimization **-O3** which changes everything.

With the optimizations, the function body gets squashed to almost nothing:

```
void simple_call(){ PORTB |= _BV(1); }
 264:   29 9a           sbi 0x05, 1 ; 5
 266:   08 95           ret
```

That is 2 + 4 ticks.  The compiler gurus have coded the compiler to figure out a much better way to execute the one line of C++.  But wait there is more.  When you "call" your function the compiler says "why do that? it is just one assembler instruction".  The compiler decides your call is pointless and puts the instructions inline:

```
void simple_call(){ PORTB |= _BV(1); }
 2d6:   29 9a           sbi 0x05, 1 ; 5
```

But with the optimizations, the function pointer call remains a call:

```
simple();
 2d8:   e0 91 0a 02     lds r30, 0x020A
 2dc:   f0 91 0b 02     lds r31, 0x020B
 2e0:   19 95           eicall
```

So lets see if the math adds up.  With the inline, the "call" is 3 ticks.  The indirect call is 8 + 6 = 14.  The difference is 11 ticks!  (I can add!)

So that is **why*.

> how do I speed it up?

**You don't need to**:  It is only 4 clock ticks more to make a function pointer call.  Except for the most trivial functions, it does not matter.

**You can't**:  Even if you try to inline the functions, you still need a conditional branch.  A bunch of load, compare, and conditional jumps will take more than the indirect call.  In other words, the function pointer is a better method of branching than any conditional.